# asp net: File Exists returns false for UNC path but doesn't when accessing via localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web site that requests users access via IIS 6 using Integrated Windows authentication then there is a section of the webpage that tests whether a file is present using:

```
File.Exists(sourcePath)
```

Where the sourcePath is a UNC that the user should be able to access. Currently my issue that while the user can access this UNC path outside of the web site I get a false result.

Now the strange thing is that the test is successfully if I use

```
http://localhost/Site
```

on the server hosting the website but fails if I use

```
http://[machine name]/Site
```

This feels like a permissions issue but struggling to nail down the cause of this.

*Extra details:*

- UNC path is on a NAS server
- web config has **identity impersonate="true"**
- Tried adding user configuration for a user with access to the UNC in the app pool. No change in issue

Comment: What does your sourcePath look like?  Without giving us any sensitive information of course.  `http://localhost/Site` and `http://[machine name]/Site` are not UNC paths.

Comment: @McCee Example sourcePath is something like \\\[NAS Server]\share\directory\example.pdf

Comment: When setting `identity impersonate="true"`, are you giving a specific login account?  i.e. `<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />`

Comment: @McCee No I wasn't. When I did add the username/password the File.Exists test works.

Comment: Excellent.  For posterity, I'll move this to the answers and then please mark the question as Answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to make sure that you are explicitly setting the user name and password when impersonating an identity for UNC paths, like so:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with Kerberos. I'd guess that there isn't an [SPN configured](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/df979570-81f6-4586-83c6-676bb005b13e.mspx?mfr=true) correctly for the identity the app pool is running under.